# How to reuse library dependencies without redeclaring in the referenced java application

Tags: java

We built a java library com.company.aws-s3:1.0.0 using the following dependency

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.12.472'
```

I would like to incorporate com.company.aws-s3:1.0.0 into a separate application, but build.gradle expects me to declare com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk dependency for interfaces which we have in com.company.aws-s3:1.0.0.

Is there a way to avoid redeclaring the com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk dependency since its already declared in com.company.aws-s3:1.0.0 library.

EDIT1: I don't want to redeclare the library as I have to mention the same versions in the application as well on the com.company.aws-s3/build.gradle file. I just want to remove the dependency on the application

Comment: What is "it", what command do you run? what error do you get?

Comment: "it" refers to build.gradle file for the separate application

Comment: Why do you share the dependency in Maven format if you asking about Gradle? Share how it is defined in your Gradle script.

Comment: @aled hope its clear, fingers crossed

Comment: @tgdavies there is no error, its just duplicate definition of dependecy which I would prefer to avoid. Hope its clear

Comment: So, you are working on `library-a` that depends on/uses `dependency-z`, and in your project, when adding `library-a`, Graddle also asks for `dependency-z`, right? And you ask how to add `library-a` without adding `dependency-z`. Is that correct?

Comment: @JettoMartínez yes

Comment: Just replace `implementation` with `api` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the dependency of that application again with an explicit version. Gradle will then either resolve that two version of the common dependency into one, or it will fail.

(See the [Declaring dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html) in the Gradle user guide for more details.)

You can also specify ranges of acceptable versions of your dependencies with `[`, `(`, `)` and `]` for "from including", "from excluding", "to excluding", "to including". See [Declaring Versions and Ranges](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html) for details there.

The explicit version specification for both parts is important for the lifetime of your application development because if that commonly used library changes in a way that makes it incompatible, you do not have to rely on the compiler failing to compiler either your own lib or your own application, but you will get a dependency resolution error from Gradle if things "run out of bounds", and can then decide for a manual resolution of that problem.

Usually with two simple version numbers for the same dependency, Gradle just includes the higher version into the build result.